# Any API gateway solution which has plugin to output data into Kafka

Tags: apache-kafka, api-gateway, ibm-api-management

I need to ingest data into my application. There is a Kafka stream already build for data ingestion. One of the client's requirement needs an API interface for accepting the data. So I need an API management solution which provides API gateway functionality and is able to produce message on a Kafka topic.

I have analyzed Kong + Kong-upstream plugin. But looking for any other similar solution

Comment: Voting to close as looking for off site resources.

Comment: @OneCricketeer what do you mean by "looking for off site resources" ?

Comment: Refer [help] - Asking for books, tools, libraries (sources external to Stackoverflow) are considered off topic questions

Answer (score 2):

You can check [WSO2 Api Manager](https://wso2.com/api-manager/).

check this article for wso2 kafka integration. https://ei.docs.wso2.com/en/7.2.0/micro-integrator/references/connectors/kafka-connector/kafka-connector-producer-example/

Also you can write your custom mediator for WSO2.

**Another Solution;**

If you need different solution else that api gateway. You can check [Apache Nifi](https://nifi.apache.org). It's application that you create your flow. You can do anything what you want.

[Apache Nifi's Documentation](https://nifi.apache.org/docs.html)

For your problem you need to check this Apache Nifi's processors;

-[PublishKafka + ConsumeKafka](https://nifi.apache.org/docs.html)
-[ListenHTTP](https://nifi.apache.org/docs.html)

*Edit after @OneCricketeer's comment:*

**Kafka Solution Without any Integration**

[Kafka REST Proxy](https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-rest)

Comment: The Kafka REST Proxy is more straightforward to install and setup than Nifi, though

Comment: You'r right. Thanks for your comment.

Comment: @G.Guvenal I am looking towards an API gateway which proxies the request to a stream. Will check WSO2

Comment: @Hatz That's exactly what the Kafka REST Proxy does. You shouldn't need a "gateway", just a backend server that forwards requests to a kafka producer

Comment: Testing with JMeter I came to around 5000 req/sec that can be ingested in Kafka with Kafka Rest Proxy. I know there are a lot of details to think and setup for this kind of testing(internet speed, no. of replicas, threads...) but in general, what is/can be the throughput of Kafka Rest Proxy -> Kafka pipeline if I'm not batching messages? Any experiences?